# Why does this integral not compute?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, warning-messages

I have the following set of equations:

$$
T_{man} (\phi_{max}, p_{max}) := \frac{\phi_{max}}{p_{max}}
$$
$$
\dot\phi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max},t) := \begin{cases} 0 & t<T_{trig} \\ p_{max} & T_{trig} < t < T_{trig} + T_{man} (\phi_{max}, p_{max}) \\
0  & T_{trig} + T_{man} (\phi_{max}, p_{max}) < t \end{cases}
$$
$$
\phi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max}, \phi_0,t) := \int_0^t \dot\phi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max},\tau)\,d\tau + \phi_0
$$
$$
\dot \chi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max}, \phi_0, V_{ac}, t) := \frac{g_0}{V_{ac}} \tan(\phi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max}, \phi_0,t))
$$
$$
\chi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max}, \phi_0, V_{ac}, \chi_{ac0}, t) := \int_0^t \dot \chi_{ac} (T_{trig}, \phi_{max}, p_{max}, \phi_0, V_{ac}, k) \, dk + \chi_{ac0}
$$

In Mathematica:

```
g0 = 9.81;

Tman[\[Phi]max_, pmax_] := \[Phi]max / pmax;

D\[Phi]ac[Ttrig_, \[Phi]max_, pmax_, t_] := If[Ttrig < t < Ttrig + Tman[\[Phi]max, pmax], pmax, 0];

\[Phi]ac[Ttrig_, \[Phi]max_, pmax_, \[Phi]0_, t_] := Integrate[D\[Phi]ac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, \[Tau]],{\[Tau],0,t}] + \[Phi]0;

DXac[Ttrig_, \[Phi]max_, pmax_, \[Phi]0_, Vac_, t_] := 
  g0*Tan[\[Phi]ac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, \[Phi]0, t]]/Vac;

Xac[Ttrig_, \[Phi]max_, pmax_, \[Phi]0_, Vac_, Xac0_, t_] := Integrate[DXac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, \[Phi]0, Vac, k], {k, 0, t}, Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]] + Xac0;
```

When I try to do some plots, the following 2 are succesful:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[\[Phi]ac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, 0, t], {t, 0, 150}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {-30*\[Pi]/180, 70*\[Pi]/180}}] ,
 {Ttrig , 0, 50} ,
 {pmax , \[Pi]/180, 5*\[Pi]/180},
 {\[Phi]max, 20*\[Pi]/180, 60*\[Pi]/180}]


Manipulate[
 Plot[DXac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, 0, 45, t], {t, 0, 150}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {-0.2, 0.5}}] ,
 {Ttrig , 0, 50} ,
 {pmax , \[Pi]/180, 5*\[Pi]/180},
 {\[Phi]max, 20*\[Pi]/180, 60*\[Pi]/180}]
```

But the last one is not:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Xac[Ttrig, \[Phi]max, pmax, 0, 45, 0, t], {t, 0, 150}
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 150}, {0, \[Pi]}}] ,
 {Ttrig , 0, 50} ,
 {pmax , \[Pi]/180, 5*\[Pi]/180},
 {\[Phi]max, 20*\[Pi]/180, 60*\[Pi]/180}]$$$
```

and I keep getting

> Integrate::pwrl: Unable to prove that integration limits {0,k} are real. Adding assumptions may help.

despite the explicit assumption that k is real (as you can see above).
After a while a plot appears, but is on an error-red background/highlighting, and changing the Manipulate[] variables sometimes leads to nothing being shown.

Is there some mistake in my code? Should I use a different function? Should I change my variable names?

Comment: If it is relevant, I have Mathematica 11.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you simplify some of your definitions as follows:

```
g0 = 9.81;
Tman[ϕmax_, pmax_] = ϕmax/pmax; (* No need to have SetDelayed here *)

(*Express your If condition as a Boole expression within Integrate, then        *)
(*pre-calculate the integral explicitly rather than re-calculating it every time*)
ϕac[Ttrig_, ϕmax_, pmax_, ϕ0_, t_] = 
    Integrate[Boole[Ttrig < t < Ttrig + Tman[ϕmax, pmax]], {τ, 0, t}] + ϕ0;

(* Once more, no need for SetDelayed here; just define it once and for all *)
DXac[Ttrig_, ϕmax_, pmax_, ϕ0_, Vac_, t_] = g0*Tan[ϕac[Ttrig, ϕmax, pmax, ϕ0, t]]/Vac;


(* The following value is only used for plotting, i.e. numerically,          *)
(* so use NIntegrate instead of Integrate, but use NumericQ to evaluate only *)
(* after numeric values have been assigned to all variables                  *)
Xac[Ttrig_?NumericQ, ϕmax_?NumericQ, pmax_?NumericQ, 
    ϕ0_?NumericQ, Vac_?NumericQ, Xac0_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[DXac[Ttrig, ϕmax, pmax, ϕ0, Vac, k], {k, 0, t}] + Xac0;
```

You can then work with your Manipulate (although I still recommend that you limit the number of [`PlotPoints`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html) used; you could also look into setting a low value for [`MaxRecursion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)):

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[
    Xac[Ttrig, ϕmax, pmax, 0, 45, 0, t], {t, 0, 90}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 40
  ],
  {Ttrig, 0, 50}, 
  {pmax, π/180, 5*π/180},
  {ϕmax, 20*π/180, 60*π/180}
]
```

it's not very pretty, but you now obtain a plot at least.

Comment: Later on I need Xac for further computation. I used the plot only to check that the integral was working, and I posted only what was needed to get the error. I'll try anyway everything you suggested, hopefully it will help me. Thank you!